# efficient vectorized replace on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to replace floats with string in a (large) dataframe and I need to speedup the operation (pandas replace function is quite slow).
Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,1.0],[0.0,np.nan]])
dic = {0.0:'a',1.0:'b'}

print('before:')
print(df)
print('after:')
print(df.applymap(lambda x: dic[x] if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan))
```

Is there a vectorized / more efficient way of doing this?

Many thanks

Comment: how many values in dictionary?

Comment: Not sure why you share the `applymap` option, which unlike `replace` that *will* be very poor from a performance point of view. If a single `replace` is too slow though, perhaps you should by looking a other options other than pandas

Comment: One idea is use `df.apply(lambda x: x.map(dic))`, but is replace to `NaN` if no match, then should be use `df.apply(lambda x: x.map(dic)).fillna(df)` but I guess performance still not very nice...

Comment: sorry I forgot few informations: the dictionary has few values (less than 10), the df is big and full of nan..

Comment: u mind showing visual of ur before and after, cos running ur code as u shared doesn't change the dataframe

Comment: blimey. worked now. my bad

Comment: I do some test in `np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1,2,3,5,np.nan], size=(1000, 1000)))
dic = {0.0:'a',1.0:'b', 2:'c',3:'d',5:'e'}` and still `replace` was fastest